# IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a Spring boot project and, until yesteday, IntelliJ IDEA (ultimate version) was recognizing its structure perfectly. I've downloaded the project again from a git repository and now it looks like a bunch of random files...
As example, it does not recognize when a directory tree is a package and I have to pass through all the folders (before it was recognized as a package).

How can I restore the previous setting? I don't think I changed anything... on purpose at least.

Thanks

EDIT:

I'll share a screen of the problem now: the test folder looks like a regular directory and does not recognize the spring code
[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried Invalidate caches? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory and open/import it again from `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`.

Comment: I've tried both and I managed to have back the right look and feel for the main directory. Still I have the test directory that looks like a regular folder and does not recognize the spring code inside

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle? Additional source directories must be defined explicitly via the build file configuration.

Comment: I use gradle. But the build.gradle file remained unchanged so it seems strange to me...

Comment: What section of your `build.gradle` defines `systemTest` as the tests source root?

Comment: thanks @CrazyCoder for the insight. There was a problem defining systemTest indeed